# Detect Single/Double/Long Key Press on keyboard (Autoit)

Tags: autoit

Please, help me, how write code on Autoit for detect

Single Key Press - On the keyboard pressed the button once

Double Key Press - On the keyboard quickly pressed the button twice

Long Key Press - On the keyboard I pressed and hold the button

Thank You!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good starting point example. Press "a" e.g. one or two times and this will be detected.

```
HotKeySet("a", "pressed")
Dim $i = 0, $PushTime = 1000

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func pressed()
    $i += 1
    Sleep($PushTime)
    Switch $i
        Case 1
            put(1)
        Case 2
            put(2)
        Case 3
            put(3)
        Case 4
            Exit (0)
    EndSwitch
    $i = 0
EndFunc   ;==>pressed

Func put($y)
    MsgBox(0, "Func called: ", "Nr: " & $y)
EndFunc   ;==>put
```